# File sending failed on Linux but works on Windows

Tags: ssh, file-transfer

I am behind an unknown network and connect to a server through that network and `ssh`. File transferring worked OK at first, but the network provider made some changes, and after that I faced problems transferring files.

If I use Windows, `ssh` and `rsync` are OK, but when I use Linux and bash, I couldn't `ssh` to the server or `rsync` files to it.
I investigated the  problem and learned some points:

1. If I use the `-oKexAlgorithms=ecdh-sha2-nistp521` option in `ssh` I can connect to the remote server.
2. `rsync` is stuck when sending files even though I use this option. I mean `rsync -azvP ... ...` created the folder tree, but the progress bar stays on '0' when trying to send the files.
3. I can send a bit file with `ssh -oKexAlgorithms=ecdh-sha2-nistp521 ... "cat > file" <file`. but very limited size
4. I can also send bit lines with `nc`. Maybe a file with 1k size.
5. I tried sshfs, ssh tunnel, but couldn't send the file.
6. MTU on both OS is the same

I am trying to understand why `ssh` and sending files work with Windows using *powershell* *winscp* and *mobaxterm* but fail on Linux.

Comment: "_rsync stuck to sending files_" - what exactly happens? What exact command are you using?

Comment: Please add `netsh interface ipv4 show subinterface` from your working Windows system and also `ip link` from your Linux-based system. In particular the MTU value for your network interface

Comment: Please put that extra detail into your question. Don't put it in the comments where it will get missed

Comment: First thing to try is `ssh -v ...` from the Linux machine. Try the same from the MS-Windows shell. Check the logs on the server.

Comment: You could try adding the option to your ~/.ssh/config for that particular host.

Comment: Is your MTU set appropriately for the network?

Comment: @bk2204,you meant the network's admin set 'mtu' only for Unix os?

Comment: No, I mean different MTUs can sometimes manifest with different behaviour on different OSes.  This sounds a lot like a network problem in general.

Comment: Ok, I'm checking and inform you,but I don't think this is the reason.

Comment: Maybe Windows uses another routing. When you do your tests on Windows and Linux, are you doing these tests on the exact same computer (dual boot) at the exact same position (same network connection)?

Comment: yes @paladin, all things are the same, only OS is different.

Comment: I'm least knowledgeable about ssh, but, can you use ftp/fxp successfully?  Might be name resolution, not ARP, especially since ISP changes caused it.

Comment: @JayCravens, no,because as I told I can send near 1k with nc and 1M when I set rsync to use nc.